# How to add custom fonts to iOS app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add a custom font into my iOS project. However, it seems that the "Info.plist" file is no longer included in iOS projects after the most recent update to Xcode.
All of the articles I am finding says to edit the Info.plist file and add a key "Font provided by application". However, this does not work. I also checked the documentation on Apple's website and it says the same thing about the Info.plist file.
So my question is, what is the new way to add custom fonts into our iOS projects?

Comment: When you say "most recent update to Xcode", do you mean Xcode 14.3.1 or Xcode 15.0 beta 7?

Comment: For an actual example project, see https://github.com/mattneub/FontTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Info tab of your target. Select a row in the "Custom iOS Target Properties" list and tap the little + icon. Then select "Fonts provided by Application".

[image]

Then expand the new entry and enter the name of the font file. Make sure the case matches exactly.

[image]

And of course you need to add the file to the project using the menu File | Add Files to "Project"...

Comment: Thank you SO much! This worked and was easy to follow/read. I hope you have a wonderful day. :)